# Selective loading of data from text file into arrays

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, data-structures, pandas

I find myself having trouble extracting data from a data logging file correctly. My data source file looks like this:

```
 0.80 1.20 3.00 3.00 0.05 0.01 0.60 0.35 0.45 1
 2.00E-02 2.020 0.700 0.173 0.053 0.482 0.099 0
 1.00E+08 0.00E+00 4.00E-01 0.00E+00 0.00E+00 3
 1.00E+03 0.00E+00 0.00E+00 1.00E+00 1.00E-04 0
 0 0 0.00E+00 1 0.10E+02 0.50 0.00
 1 700.0 0   0.0 0.00 1 1 0.10E-02 0.10E+04

   4.999526E+00  7.821430E+01  1.098711371E+08 
 Remeshing model

  K      P         rho         T          r    
 999  4.170E+23  6.164E+06  1.577E+08  2.584E-0
 998  4.014E+23  6.004E+06  1.599E+08  8.277E-0
 997  3.859E+23  5.843E+06  1.622E+08  1.152E-0
 996  3.705E+23  5.682E+06  1.646E+08  1.411E-0
 995  3.553E+23  5.520E+06  1.673E+08  1.638E-0
 994  3.401E+23  5.357E+06  1.701E+08  1.844E-0
 993  3.252E+23  5.193E+06  1.730E+08  2.036E-0
 992  3.104E+23  5.029E+06  1.762E+08  2.218E-0
 991  2.957E+23  4.864E+06  1.795E+08  2.393E-0
 990  2.813E+23  4.699E+06  1.831E+08  2.563E-0

 989  2.671E+23  4.534E+06  1.870E+08  2.729E-0
 988  2.530E+23  4.368E+06  1.911E+08  2.892E-0
 987  2.392E+23  4.202E+06  1.957E+08  3.052E-0
 986  2.257E+23  4.036E+06  2.006E+08  3.212E-0
 985  2.124E+23  3.870E+06  2.060E+08  3.371E-0
 984  1.993E+23  3.703E+06  2.118E+08  3.530E-0
 983  1.866E+23  3.537E+06  2.183E+08  3.690E-0
 982  1.741E+23  3.371E+06  2.254E+08  3.851E-0
 981  1.620E+23  3.205E+06  2.332E+08  4.013E-0
 980  1.502E+23  3.039E+06  2.417E+08  4.177E-0

 979  1.388E+23  2.874E+06  2.508E+08  4.344E-0
 978  1.277E+23  2.710E+06  2.604E+08  4.513E-0
 977  1.170E+23  2.547E+06  2.704E+08  4.686E-0
```

(this is just a tiny piece of it but essentially should be enough to show my problem. the actual file has about 1.6 million lines, so processing speed must be a high priority...)

What i need to now, is to import the columns under the

```
 K      P         rho         T          r
```

row into separate arrays. But that's not all of it... this table of lines from 999 down to 1 reoccurs  every few hundred or thousand lines with differing values (except the "K" part, which will always be 999 to 1).

I would like to import each column of data into an array or something equivalent. (maybe a 1d array would be better for performance than a 2d array).

So in the end, I would like to end up with arrays looking more or less like this:

```
K = [999, 998, 997, ... , 2, 1]
P = [ ........................]
rho = [ ........................]
and so on...
```

I was thinking about scanning through the file line by line with `.readline()` and checking each line for being the one with `"K, P, rho and T"` and then, if found, importing the next thousand lines or so with `np.loadtext()`. But it was just an idea and probably quite awful to do.

Another problem is those empty lines every ten lines, that I presume were implemented for human readability. I don't know if they are a problem to my idea of an approach.

EDIT:
I think a have found a possible solution... but is it a "good" methode?

```
K = []
P = []
Density = []
Temp  = []
Radius = []
Mass = []

outTP = open('../Data/out_TP1-9', 'r')
line = outTP.readline()
i = 0
j = 0
while line:
    if line[:10] == "  K      P":
        i += 1
        K.append([])
        P.append([])
        Density.append([])
        Temp.append([])
        Radius.append([])
        Mass.append([])
        n = 0
        while n < 999:
            line = outTP.readline()
            if line == '\n':
                line = outTP.readline()
            data = np.array(line.split())
            data = data.astype(np.float)
            K[i-1].append(data[0])
            P[i-1].append(data[1])
            Density[i-1].append(data[2])
            Temp[i-1].append(data[3])
            Radius[i-1].append(data[4])
            Mass[i-1].append(data[7])
            n += 1
    j += 1
    line = outTP.readline()
print len(K), type(K), type(K[0]), type(K[0][0])
return K, Temp, Mass, Radius, Density
```

So I end up with a 2d list of floats for each parameter with the first dimension being the number of occurrence and the second dimension the value itself.

would you agree or does anyone think there is definitely a better way? (which there most certainly will be...)

Comment: Your approach sounds like a good idea to me. Have you tried it?

Comment: Not yet, I'm still trying to figure out how :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check it:

```
file = 'c:\\file.txt'

k = []
p = []
rho = []
t = []
r = []

with open(file) as f:
    lines = f.read().splitlines()

i = 999
for line in lines:
    line = line.strip()
    if line.startswith(str(i)):
        lineSplitted = line.split('  ')
        k.append(lineSplitted[0])
        p.append(lineSplitted[1])
        rho.append(lineSplitted[2])
        t.append(lineSplitted[3])
        r.append(lineSplitted[4])
        i-=1
```

Comment: very nice idea. is almost what i came up with a few minutes ago

Comment: kind of helped, gave me a good idea to get something to work. :)